# Android App to BlackBerry Playbook - Google Maps Issue

Tags: android, blackberry, porting

I'm porting my android app to playbook and keep getting an error related to not supporting Google Maps, however I don't use that anywhere in my project. It's also not mentioned anywhere in my manifest.

I'm at a loss here, not sure what to do next. Any ideas?

---

Just to update on this: I was able to compile and run the app on the emulator w/ that warning present so - lets see if it gets past approval process, will update.

Comment: Is your build target set to be one that has the Google APIs?

Comment: I'm pointing to the PlayBook VM as a Run target if that's what you mean. If not how would I check for that? Forgive my unfamiliarity as I come from .NET/VS world :)

Comment: You really should consider significantly augmenting your question. For example, "getting an error"... from what? (Eclipse? The Playbook? Something else?) What is the precise error message? When does this message appear? And so on.

Comment: Certainly, here's some additional info: a) This appears in a form of a warning, here's a screenshot http://screencast.com/t/PlKVB4Bkqe b) however I am able to run successfully on the playbook VM c) RIM's online Android-to-Playbook validation tool reports the same message

Comment: I have never seen that warning, so I haven't a clue. Sorry.

Comment: I thought you couldn't use Google API's with the playbook, therefore you couldn't use the Google Maps widget. Please not the word "thought" - I am desperately trying to cite this however I cleared my history recently.

Comment: Not using either, as mentioned above :)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API for Android is unsupported on the Blackberry Playbook. See https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/ for a list of what can and cannot be ported.

For now, there is no way around this. If you want to create a Google Maps application for the Playbook, you will need to use the AIR SDK with the Google Maps Flash API